# Unbalanced RX data when using network bonding in mode-4

Tags: networking, linux-networking, bonding

We use a dual network card server with bond in 802.3ad mode.

```
# cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v5.14.21

Bonding Mode: IEEE 802.3ad Dynamic link aggregation
Transmit Hash Policy: layer3+4 (1)
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0
Peer Notification Delay (ms): 0

802.3ad info
LACP rate: slow
Min links: 0
Aggregator selection policy (ad_select): stable
System priority: 65535
System MAC address: 0c:xx:xx:xx:99:40
Active Aggregator Info:
    Aggregator ID: 1
    Number of ports: 2
    Actor Key: 21
    Partner Key: 13
    Partner Mac Address: 00:xx:5e:00:01:00

Slave Interface: enP1p1s0f0
MII Status: up
Speed: 25000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 0c:xx:xx:xx:99:40
Slave queue ID: 0
Aggregator ID: 1
Actor Churn State: none
Partner Churn State: none
Actor Churned Count: 0
Partner Churned Count: 0
details actor lacp pdu:
    system priority: 65535
    system mac address: 0c:xx:xx:xx:99:40
    port key: 21
    port priority: 255
    port number: 1
    port state: 61
details partner lacp pdu:
    system priority: 65535
    system mac address: 00:xx:5e:00:01:00
    oper key: 13
    port priority: 255
    port number: 14
    port state: 61

Slave Interface: enP1p1s0f1
MII Status: up
Speed: 25000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 0c:xx:xx:xx:99:41
Slave queue ID: 0
Aggregator ID: 1
Actor Churn State: none
Partner Churn State: none
Actor Churned Count: 0
Partner Churned Count: 0
details actor lacp pdu:
    system priority: 65535
    system mac address: 0c:xx:xx:xx:99:40
    port key: 21
    port priority: 255
    port number: 2
    port state: 61
details partner lacp pdu:
    system priority: 65535
    system mac address: 00:xx:5e:00:01:00
    oper key: 13
    port priority: 255
    port number: 32782
    port state: 61
```

The outgoing data on both network cards is balanced, but the incoming  is concentrated on one network card.

```
bond0: flags=5187<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MASTER,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet xxx.xxx.165.215  netmask 255.255.255.192  broadcast xxx.xxx.165.255
    inet6 xxxx::xxx:a1ff:fe5a:9940  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 0c:xx:xx:xx:99:40  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 286959178  bytes 327689609899 (305.1 GiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 24884  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 394378427  bytes 477465769012 (444.6 GiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 10 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enP1p1s0f0: flags=6211<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SLAVE,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 0c:xx:xx:xx:99:40  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 7184101080  bytes 9239686504798 (8.4 TiB) <= MOST DATA
    RX errors 0  dropped 42969  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 4769768089  bytes 6383749337305 (5.8 TiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enP1p1s0f1: flags=6211<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SLAVE,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 0c:xx:xx:xx:99:40  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 129986535  bytes 186499719199 (173.6 GiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 1294  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 4073423613  bytes 5403193492511 (4.9 TiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I have two questions:

1. Why RX packets not balanced in both NICs?
2. Why does each statistic of bond0 not equal to the sum of enP1p1s0f0 and enP1p1s0f1?

additional information：
This server is linked to a stacked switch, is it related to the imbalance?

Answer (score 0):

> Why RX packets not balanced in both NICs?

Generally, they aren't. Distibuting traffic over LACP LAG for the NIC Rx side is the switch's job. Traffic distribution is often done by an index derived from a hash over the source/destination IP addresses and port numbers, but there's really no standard way - check the manual/config for details.

Hash-based distribution ensures that the packet order within each flow doesn't change - which would hurt performance much more than a maxed out physical link.

Answer (score 0):

(this is really a continuation of an idea from @Zac67's answer)

LACP's Hash-based distribution is designed so with the ideal hash and infinite number of streams, spread can be made even (but think "L2"-based hash on both sides connecting L3-routers; they will ever load only one link). Anything else will lead to non-even spread, and father from the ideal, worse the spread. In the limit of a single flow, it will either take one path or another, not balancing anything at all.

There are no standards, but there are *typical* configurations: MAC addresses of a source and destination, or *IP's and ports*. Read your switch manual of what it can do. For example, if you find out that "L2"-balancing (based on MACs) works good for you, stick with it. "L3+4" behaves less predictably (but "more even in the average"!), because it depends on port numbers which are random.

Statistics won't ever match exactly. First of all, this is all dynamic and it is impossible to start everything in a transactional style, so all statistics starts counting simultaneously. Then, you can destroy and re-create your bond live without downing members, which will reset its statistics, but not statistics in members — and voila, nothing matches. Looks like something like this actually happened with your system. You can separate and enslave back the member as well, with the similar effect. Or you can just reset the statistics.

And second, members also have to send and receive LACP DU's, which are counted in members statistics and aren't propagated to the bond. And, depending on your configured LACP rate, DUs can be sent each second — counting numbers up.